# No se envía un correo con php

Tags: php, email

he escrito el código para enviar un correo en formato html:

```
$nom = $_POST["nom"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$tema = $_POST["tema"];
$missatge = $_POST["missatge"];

$tot = "<b>Nom: </b>".$nom."<br><b>Email/Telèfon: </b>".$email."<br><b>Assumpte: </b>".$tema."<br><b>Missatge: </b>".nl2br($missatge);
$tot .= "<br><br><b>Atenció:</b> per contestar a ".$nom." cal comunicar a <b>".$email."</b>, no per la direcció d'aquest correu <b><i>(web@gabinetedeautiroria.com)</i></b>";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Gabinete Web <web@gabinetedeautiroria.com>' . "\r\n";

mail("micorreo", "Nou missatge de la pàgina web de Gabinete", $tot, $headers);
```

El problema está en que no recibo mi correo y tampoco me dice que hay un error.

Comment: El que no te lo diga no significa que no haya error. Para saber si hay error hay que revisar el archivo llamado error_log o parecido que suele estar en la carpeta root o donde se encuentra el archivo PHP.

Comment: Deberías indicar si el código está en localhost o en un hosting. Y las características de tu servidor web. Versión PHP, etc.

Comment: Tal como te dice @Piropeator, no tiene que haber un error a nivel de código o de ejecución. Puede que la configuración del servidor no permita el envío de email o aun enviándolo, los filtros antispam estén rechazando los emails que envías. Tendrás que compartir con nosotros, para empezar, la configuración de tu servidor.

Comment: Uso versión de php 5.4

Comment: Es raro que poniendo text/plain funcione pero con text/html no? Que es el que pretendo conseguir

Answer (score 0):

Sustituye "micorreo" por $email.

Comment: Hola, A. Pascual. Para que la respuesta, que es correcta, sea aún mas útil, no solo para el autor de la pregunta, sino para posibles usuarios que se enfrenten en otro momento a un problema parecido, ¿podrías señalar cuál es el origen del error? Una breve explicación sería suficiente. Se trata de comprender como funciona el método `mail()`.

Comment: He puesto micorreo para no poner una direccion de correo real, de hecho, si pongo text/plain, funciona pero con text/html no, que es lo que quiero conseguir.

Answer (score 0):

he encontrado una solución cambiando los headers:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: example@example.com>\r\n"."X-Mailer: php";
```